# Tool to check Android strings.xml variables?

Tags: android, validation, localization

A simple typo in an Android localization variable (for instance `%1d` instead of `%1$d` in `strings.xml`) can lead to a [crash](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=359).

We can't afford to test exhaustively (many screens, some very rarely shown, tens of languages, very frequent releases, no revenue) so we must find a smarter way. Those errors are not shown in Eclipse, and actually I am looking for a non-visual tool so that it can be called by our automatic release tool.

I wrote the following script to check the localisation files:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Spot malformed string replacement patterns in Android localization files.

grep -R "%1$ s" values*
grep -R "%1$ d" values*

grep -R '%' values* |
 sed -e 's/%/\n%/g' | # Split lines that contain several expressions
 grep '%'           | # Filter out lines that do not contain expressions
 grep -v ' % '      | # Lone % character, not a variable
 grep -v '%<'       | # Same, at the end of the string
 grep -v '% '       | # Same, at the beginning of the string
 grep -v '%で'      | # Same, no spaces in Japanese
 grep -v '%s'       | # Single string variable
 grep -v '%d'       | # Single decimal variable
 grep -v '%[0-9][0-9]\?$s' | # Multiple string variable
 grep -v '%[0-9][0-9]\?$d' |  # Multiple decimal variable
 grep -v '%1$.1f'   | # ?
 grep -v '%.1f'

grep -R '％' values*
```

PROBLEM: It [fails](http://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=1034) to catch problems in Arabic localization files.

QUESTION: rather than re-inventing the wheel, is there already such a validation tool? (not Eclipse)
If not: what checks did I forget?

Note: [this script is open source](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/master/tools/find-broken-strings-variables.sh)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this problem, but it sounds like something that should be fixed by the Lint tool in ADT. Perhaps you should ask [Tor Norbye](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116539451797396019960/posts).

Comment: @DavidCaunt: Thanks! I submitted an enhancement request to Lint: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26434

Comment: @DavidCaunt: Looks like ADT 17 will be the solution, when released :-) Could you please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done, feel free to edit/add your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something that should be incorporated into the Lint tool in ADT.

Comment: Will be in the future ADT 17: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26434

Comment: Available in ADT 18 and 19, usage: `lint --check StringFormatInvalid .`